# Primefaces CKEditor hardcoded pixel width?

Tags: ckeditor, primefaces-extensions

I'm using Primefaces 3.5 and primefaces-extensions 0.7.1 with CKEditor. I'm trying to set the width of the editor using a site wide CSS config file in which I specify properties for the class of the `span` tag generated to wrap the editor area. My problem is that this `span` tag also get an attribute `style="width: 600px;"` which overrides the properties from the class.

I verified using Firefox dev tools that if this attribute was not present my class style properties would take effect and I would get the result I am looking for but I don't know why this attribute is added by CKEditor so I cant remove it.

It seems very odd to me that there would be a hard coded pixel value in CKEditor but I can't see anything in my application that would set it. So I wonder if anyone else have had this problem and perhaps a solution.

EDIT:
PS. I looked at the html generated by CKEditor on a Primefaces Extensions showcase site [showcase site](http://fractalsoft.net/primeext-showcase-mojarra/views/ckEditor.jsf) and it also contained the mysterious `style="width: 600px"`attribute which makes me more confident that it's nothing in my own application that is setting the value.

EDIT: Updating to primefaces-extensions 1.0.0 did not help

Answer (score 0):

You may just use the **width** attribute of **pe:ckEditor** tag, for example:

```
<pe:ckEditor id="my_editor" width="800px" value="#{myBean.message}" />
```

or

```
<pe:ckEditor id="my_editor" width="50%" value="#{myBean.message}" />
```

I'm using Primefaces 4.0 and Primefaces Extensions 1.2.1 and resources-ckeditor 1.2.1 and it works great.